# Is there any framework/technology supporting embedding XML into XML recursively?

Tags: xml, data-structures, recursion, embedding

Let assume I have a set of arbitrary XML's that I would like to embed into each other recursively. Is there any technology or framework helping with this? I am looking for something adding, removing and searching XML's within XML's.

**EDIT**

Someone removed the recursion tag from my question. I guess I am not making myself clear. Let's imagine XML's represent data structures instances referring each other. Is there a technology/framework handling this?

**EDIT II**

Someone claims I am not talking about *recursion*, but about *circular references* at best. I am not excluding the possibility of having one data structure referencing itself (by instance or by definition, it does not matter). I DO mean *recursive* as in *fractal* so to speak, so please stop removing my tag.

Comment: How is this different than just having nested XML elements within a single XML document?

Comment: @David Boilerplate code + where is the limit between an inserted XML and the containing XML.

Comment: The limit is up to your XML parser of choice.  If you don't need the entire XML document in memory at one time, then you can use a streaming XML reader and there won't be a size limit.

Comment: what you are refering to is **not** recursion, it is circular references at best

Comment: @Jarrod I am not excluding a data structure referring to the same type of data structure/instance. I am talking 'fractal' too so to speak.

Comment: either way what you are talking about is **not** recursion. There is no ability in the XML standard to refer to other elements, thus an element can **not** by definition refer to itself. If you have some mechanism to reference other elements, it is domain specific and not related to XML. Recursion tag is erroneous in any case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not out of the box in standard XML. Basically you need to have a mechanism of recording linkage between elements in the final XML document, and then have a savvy marshalling and demarshalling tech to handle the references. This is an object serialization to XML issue, effectively.

Without it, for example, if you were to try and save a circular list, you'd end up having an infinite loop as the tail element returns to the head element and keeps writing. References fix that issue for you.

I believe XStream will do this for you out of the box (if you're in Java, but you don't mention that).

Comment: That's what I thought... I was just wondering if a solution existed out there. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way of embedding one xml document in another is to use namespaces to differentiate the content.

Sometimes people entity-encode the inner xml and embed it as a string, but that's a really bad thing to do.  Don't do it.

Answer (score 1):

Recursion in XML is handled with pairing id and idref attributes. If you want one part of an XML document to refer to another part, place an id attribute on the part you're referring to, and an idref attribute on the referrer.

As far as I know no parsers will traverse these attributes automatically, you need to do it manually.

Answer (score 1):

What about [XInclude](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/PR-xinclude-20040930/)? E.g. [XOM](http://www.xom.nu/) and [Xerces](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces2-j/faq-xinclude.html) support this extension.

Comment: XInclude is a start, but definitely not the whole package.

Comment: @JVerstry: I believe, that XSLT or any XML deserializer will not handle the case when XML refers itself. Perhaps only someone with one gold badge can answer correctly for the question of someone with two gold badges :)